# Doxygen not showing information for submodules

Tags: module, fortran, doxygen

I am using a fortran submodule, however the descriptions are 
not being shown in doxygen. How can I add to make them appear in the documentation?

```
 Submodule (Scan) Multiscan

 Implicit None

 Contains

 !> \brief 
 !>    Returns information from a single process 

 Module Procedure scan1_tg
  !...
 End Procedure scan1_tg

 !> \brief 
 !>    Returns information from two processors

 Module Procedure scan2_tg
  !...
 End Procedure scan2_tg

 !> \brief 
 !>    Returns information from 3 processors.

 Module Procedure scan3_tg
   !...
 End Procedure scan3_tg
```

Comment: I don't think Doxygen can be taught about submodules too easily. I'd recommend to have a look at FORD: https://github.com/cmacmackin/ford, if I am not mistaken it supports submodules.